# How to write a performant and easy to read if-else block?

Tags: javascript

I wonder how this code block would be written best in terms of readability and performance:

```
let color= "green"
if (value > 50) color= "yellow"
if (value > 80) color= "orange"
```

Comment: What performance issues are you having with this code?

Comment: This is fine... You're overthinking this.

Comment: "Best" questions are specifically off-topic for SO, as they invite opinion-based responses. Similarly, refactoring questions are *possibly* more appropriate at https://codereview.stackexchange.com, but [read their help first to be sure](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder This is a best practices in general question and so would be off-topic on Code Review.

Comment: Thanks @Peilonrayz.

Answer (score 1):

Put the highest value first, since it excludes the lower values. Then use `else` for the final default.

```
if (value > 80) {
    color = "orange";
} else if (value > 50) {
    color = "yellow";
} else {
    color = "green";
}
```